# Wordpress fle & directory permissions: cannot open or save with my local user

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I seem to be having a permissions issue. Following some bad tutorials, my permissions and ownership for the site directory look like this:

```
drwxrwx---  7 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  5 09:46 my-wp-site/
```

this seems to allow apache to do what it needs to do, but I cannot open any files in this dir, as a matter of fact it won't even let me move into the directory now. How do I set up permissions and ownership properly to allow for both apache and myself to read/write?

Comment: What user are you logged in as in your shell? Does that user belong to `www-data`?

Comment: @esqew 
`sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development$ grep 'www-data' /etc/group
www-data:x:33:sandra
`

Comment: `sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development$ groups
sandra adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided in your question and subsequent comments, your user `sandra` is not either the owner or part of the `www-data` group. Since the "public" bit of your permissions mode is `0`, anyone outside the folder's owner (`www-data`) or group (`www-data`) will not have any permissions to read, write, or execute the folder.

To resolve this, add user `sandra` to the `www-data` group:

```
usermod -a -G www-data sandra
```

Once completed, log out and back in (or `su sandra`, both as per [AskUbuntu - Group permissions allow, but still get permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455000/group-permissions-allow-but-still-get-permission-denied)) for the group changes to take effect.

Comment: I did this, still getting permissions denied

Comment: Can you share the new output of `groups`?

Comment: sandra@TENDesign-ubunto:~/development$ groups
sandra adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data sandra` does not seem to be adding me

Comment: Should have mentioned - using `usermod` requires the user in question to either (a) log out and back in, or (b) `su` to the same user account for the group changes to take effect.

Comment: ok that worked. i would have never know that i had to relog to do that! thanks!